# Colorized readline prompt breaks control-a

Tags: c, macos, readline

The following program prints a colorized readline prompt. It breaks control-a (the cursor ends up much farther to the right than it should be):

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

#define CYELLOW "\001\e[0;31m\002"
#define RESET   "\001\e[0m\002"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    readline(CYELLOW "prompt> " RESET);
    return 0;
}
```

control-a works when I call readline() without a colorized prompt:

```
readline("prompt> ");
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.4. Here's the output of otool:

```
/usr/lib/libreadline.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1
```

There are a couple of stackoverflow questions that seem to touch on this:

- [Colorized output breaks linewrapping with readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806643/colorized-output-breaks-linewrapping-with-readline)
- [Look how to fix column calculation in Python readline if use color prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468435/look-how-to-fix-column-calculation-in-python-readline-if-use-color-prompt)

Both of them mention that color markers need to be bracketed by \001 and \002. I followed those instructions but control-a is still broken.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your issue (using `libreadline6-dev`, 6.3-4ubuntu2 on Linux Mint). I get a red prompt using your code, but Ctrl+A works fine for me with and without coloring. I did get some wrapping issues with the code in "Colorized output breaks linewrapping with readline", so at least his issue I could reproduce.
Maybe adding library version and other details could help tracking it down.

Comment: At the shell level, you need to put `\[` and `\]` around any non-printing escape sequences in the prompt string. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt. I'm sure there's some equivalent for direct readline use but I don't know it right off.

Comment: @anol, thanks for your comment. I tried to reproduce the issue on my Ubuntu Linux machine, and was unable to -- control-a works correctly. The machine that causes me issues is my Mac (running 10.9.4). I don't believe I've installed a new version of libreadline on it, so it looks like a stock library. Here's the output of otool: /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib:
/usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1

Comment: the column counting has nothing to do with C, Ruby, python, ect.  The column counting/line wrapping is strictly a function of the terminal driver.  Commands can be given to the terminal driver, via the command line, if not otherwise, to tell the terminal driver how to handle escape sequences.

Comment: @user3629249: That's not really the case. It is true that the terminal emulator (not driver) performs column counting and line wrapping, etc. But it doesn't report the column position back to the process writing to the terminal, so if that process needs to know where on the screen a particular character is being displayed, it needs to track column positions itself. That's what makes writing libraries like readline/editline so annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X uses the NetBSD `editline` library, which includes a partial compatibility implementation of `readline`.

It appears that an attempt was made to add readline's feature of allowing the user to bracket terminal control sequences in the prompt using the characters `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE` (defined as `'\1'` and `'\2'` respectively in `readline.h`). Unfortunately, due to a small typo, the feature is never enabled in `rl_initialize`.

As I read the code (I haven't tested this), the fix would be to change line 327 of `readline.c` [see note 1] from:

```
el_set(e, EL_PROMPT, _get_prompt, RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE);
```

to:

```
el_set(e, EL_PROMPT_ESC, _get_prompt, RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE);
```

That would require you to find the source code for `libedit`, make that trivial change, reconfigure and recompile it, and then install it. I don't have a Mac so I can't guide you through that process. (See Note 1 for links to source repositories which might be useful.)

Another solution would be to use the GNU readline library in your project. It's apparently available in MacPorts, so if you use that, it should be easy enough to install.

---

#### Notes:

1. I got that line number from this [OS X source repository](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libedit/libedit-40/src/readline.c). In the [head revision of the NetBSD distribution](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libedit/readline.c?rev=1.117&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&sortby=date), it's at line 337. But it should be easy enough to find by searching for `EL_PROMPT`. Just make sure that the symbol `EL_PROMPT_ESC` is defined in `histedit.h`; if it isn't, the version of the editline library you've found is probably too old.

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the native Mac library with a fixed library somehow? Or can I statically link a fixed version into a specific binary somehow? I'm trying to use colors in my mysql prompt and this issue is making it very inconvenient. I don't have the expertise to recompile mysql with readline (google suggests it isn't supported anymore).